# Variable out of scope React

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am new to React and I've created a HelloWorld application for Jupyter Widget. Everything is working as expected, however, I can not figure out why the variable `view` is not accessible in my `clickHandler` function, even though `view` is accessible in the `componentDidMount` function when the app is rendering. Is there a way to access the global variable `view` from the `clickHandler` function?

```
export class ExampleView extends DOMWidgetView {
  initialize(){
    const view = this;
    interface AppProps{

    }
    interface AppState{
      value:any
    }
    class Hello extends React.Component<AppProps,AppState> {
      constructor(props:any){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          value: view.model.get("value")
        }
        this.clickHandler = this.clickHandler.bind(this);
      }

      onChange(model:any){
        this.setState(model.changed);
      }
      componentDidMount(){ 
        view.listenTo(view.model,"change",this.onChange.bind(this));
      }

      render(){
        return <div><h1>Hello {this.state.value}</h1><button onClick={this.clickHandler}>Submit</button></div>
      }
      clickHandler(){
        console.log("clicked")
        // this.state = {value:"set to something else"}
        this.setState(state => ({
          value: "something else"
        }));
        console.log(view) // VM1302:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: view is not defined
      }
    }

    const $app = document.createElement("div");
    const App = React.createElement(Hello);
    ReactDOM.render(App,$app);

    view.el.append($app);
  }
}
```

Comment: I have never seen classes nested like that in TypeScript or React.  Can you unnest it and pass `view` in to the Hello component as a prop?

Comment: Are you using a transpiling the code? This could be a transpilation related issue.